# How can I delete a private queue from MSMQ when all the security users have been removed?

Tags: messaging, msmq

We have a message queue on our queue server to which no-one has access. During a test we removed all the users from the queue. Now no-one can access it at all.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is a file in the system32\msmq\storage\lqs directory that contains the configuration for this queue. Find the file that contains the name of the queue you are talking about. If you delete the file and restart MSMQ, the queue has gone. Obviously don't delete any of the other files!

Answer (score -1):

Also you can run this code snippet. Note that your project should reference System.Messaging

```
using System.Messaging;

.
.

.

MessageQueue[] msmques = MessageQueue.GetPrivateQueuesByMachine(".");
foreach (var item in msmques)
{
        MessageQueue.Delete(".\\"+item.QueueName);
}
```